# php problems writing to new line in txt file

Tags: php

Please can someone tell me why when I write to a .txt file it all goes on one line. I know this is a newbie question but I am new and this code has came directly out of the book im learning from the idea is that a customer order comes in and each order written to a new line in the orders.txt file. The orders are coming through fine just not on a new line. The string code is as follows.

```
$outputstring = $date."\t".$tireqty." tires \t".$oilqty." oil\t"
                .$sparkqty." spark plugs\t\$".$totalamount
                ."\t". $address."\n";
```

Comment: there isn't enough code here

Comment: You need to show how you're writing it to the file.

Comment: In this code seems you have only one line with field separated  by tab and only newlline at the end

Comment: can you tried  " PHP_EOL " ?

Comment: I bet you're on Windows... :)

Comment: ...yeah, maybe.

Comment: what OS are you running this under? \*NIX or Windows or other? such as a MAC?

Comment: @AlexHowansky more specifically, on windows and viewing in notepad...

Comment: Yes I am using windows 10 so im guessing this is a known problem

Comment: instead of using `\n`  in your string try using `\r\n` or just PHP_EOL;.

Comment: It's not a problem, just a difference. Unix uses `\n` for EOL and Windows uses `\r\n`. Use @RanjeetSingh's suggestion and you should be good either way.

Comment: Thank you very much \r\n works :)

Comment: @AlexHowansky guessed it correctly alright; question's closed.

Comment: so would PHP_EOL work on any OS? Where would I place this in the above string?